# What does "top through view" mean for MSOP pin assignment?

Tags: datasheet

Reading the datasheet for [a USB switch](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fsusb30-d.pdf) IC, it says "top through view" for the pinout diagram (page 2). It seems like this means "looking from the top-down at the IC", where the notch is in the top left. Is that the correct assumption?

[image: MSOP pin assignment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you are looking from the top view "down through" the part. Typically the word "through" is not used (and usually top view or top down or bottom view).

Answer (score 1):

The convention is always CCW from top and CW from bottom with pin 1 indicated by a fiducial mark.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after writing this, I had another look through the datasheet and found that the physical dimensions on page 15 indicates the position of pin 1. Sharing in case someone else finds this useful.

So, I guess "top through view" means "top down view" or "top view". However, I'm unsure about the significance of the word "through" here as it's an SMD, not a through-hole mount.

Comment: "Through" probably means that the pins might not be be visible if looking from the top (as in QFP package). And this view is making it "transparent"

Comment: it may also be a translation server result

Comment: I agree with Eugene. The other packages are ones where the pins are not visible when viewing from the top. For these, "top through view" is appropriate, and necessary to distinguish from the view where you flip the chip over to see the pins. The notation was copied to the diagram for the MSOP package even though it isn't appropriate for that package.